# In Laravel, how can I test a "show" route with a parameter, after having created a model instance?

Tags: php, laravel, testing

I've got an `Idea` model which has:

- `public_id` (auto-generated)
- `title`
- `slug`
- `content`

It also has a `pretty_slug` attribute (which combines the `public_id` and the `slug`). This `pretty_slug` is used in the "show" route URL.

I want to test this "show" route which has a `/ideas/{pretty_slug}` format.

So I create an `Idea` instance, and want to use its `pretty_slug` as a parameter in the `ideas.show` route:

```php
public function test_guest_can_get_show_page()
{
    $idea = Idea::factory()->create([
        'title' => 'My awesome idea',
        'content' => 'Lorem ipsum this.'
    ]);

    $response = $this->get(route('ideas.show', ['pretty_slug' => $idea->pretty_slug]));
    $response->assertStatus(200);
}
```

This fails because the status code is `500` for some reason.

I have another similar database test which works:

```php
public function test_models_slug_is_created()
{
    Idea::factory()->create([
        'title' => 'My awesome idea',
        'content' => 'Lorem ipsum this.'
    ]);

    $this->assertDatabaseHas('ideas', [
        'slug' => 'my-awesome-idea',
    ]);
}
```

Or an "index" route test, which also works:

```php
public function test_guest_can_get_index_page()
{
    $response = $this->get(route('ideas.index'));
    $response->assertStatus(200);
}
```

I'm not sure how to do this. I haven't found any solution on the internet or the official documentation. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Try adding `$this->withoutExceptionHandling();` to your `show` test to see if you get a better error message than a `500` status code.

Comment: Thanks @Unflux. I've tried that in different places but no luck.

Comment: The 500 error often indicates you have an error in your coding. But with all the code you show, you don't show the code activated by the show route. And you need to look in your logs. A 500 error will be visible there with a full stack trace which makes it easy to find the source of the problem. See `/storage/logs` in your Laravel folder

Comment: Very helpful @MaartenVeerman thanks. I looked into the logs and my blade template was trying to access the `$idea->user` object, but in my test I'm not attaching the idea to any user.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @Maarten Veerman, a `500` error can be caused by a lot of things. I looked into the logs and my `show.blade.php` template was trying to access the `user` from the `idea`:

```php
 <p>Asked by {{ $idea->user->name }}</p>
```

But in my test I wasn't attaching any user to the idea.

I fixed my test by creating a user first, and making sure there was a relationship:

```php
public function test_guest_can_get_show_page()
{
    $user = User::factory()->create();

    $idea = Idea::factory()->make([
        'title' => 'My awesome idea',
        'content' => 'Lorem ipsum this.'
    ]);

    $user->ideas()->save($idea);

    $response = $this->get(route('ideas.show', ['pretty_slug' => $idea->pretty_slug]));
    $response->assertStatus(200);

}
```